# Image using drawableLeft does not fit inside the EditText field

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to make an image fit into the `EditText` itself using `drawableLeft`, without any `padding` or "whitespaces" around it.

This is what the image looks like for now

[image]

This is how it should look like

[image]

I tried increasing the size of the image itself but it made the `EditText` expand even more.

Here's the `XML` file:

```
 <EditText
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:id="@+id/login_password"
    android:layout_width="315dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="17dp"
    android:textColor="#8d8e8f"
    android:hint="Password"

    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/sample"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_below="@+id/login_name"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

How can the image `fit` inside the `EditText`? Does it something to do about the image itself?

Comment: Why are you using  android:layout_width="315dp" ?? use match_parent because of the static height some of the view may be left out

Comment: @RakshitNawani, unfortunately, the width should be specific (required by the instructor). I tried using the `match_parent` and the border or padding of the image still persists.

Comment: did you use paddingleft or marginLeft for the whole EditText ?

Comment: None. I did not use any kind of `padding`

Comment: try using padding left or margin left

Comment: @Scar ..Check my below solution

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha, yes sir I'm currently testing it. Sorry if it takes too long and I'm unable to respond quickly

Comment: @Scar ..Take your time..and let me know in case of concern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the `LinearLayout` for it. Means in the LinearLayout , you should put the Editext's drawable image as the background , and than divide it in to three parts,1st part is for the password_image , 2nd one for your `EditText` and and 3rd last one for is your INVISIBLE View, which prevent , your `EditText` value to touch at end

```
                   <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/EDITEXT_DRAWABLE"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:weightSum="2">

                        <ImageView

                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.4"
                            android:gravity="left|center"
                            android:src="@drawable/sample" />


                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/password_et"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_weight="1.5"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:hint="********"
                            android:inputType="textPassword"
                            android:paddingLeft="-10dp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
                            android:layout_weight="0.1"
                            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                            android:paddingRight="8dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/sample"
                            android:visibility="invisible" /> ///PUT THE VIEW INVIIBLE

                    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: as much as possible, the image should be inside the `EditText`. Although this method may be a workaround, is there no other way just to eliminate the spaces around the image when using `drawableLeft` so that the image will perfectly fit inside the `EditText`?

Comment: @Scar ..The same code , i have used in my project...And it works fine, could u plz tell me what difficulty are you currently facing?? ......      One mor e thing u can do that...You can use the RelativeLayout in place of LinearLayout and set Image ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT and than after set the Edittext rightOF these Image...Than it can be workable for you...

Comment: by using `transparent` as the color of the `background`, it made the field's `borders` invisible as well. Is there any way to retain the `borders` while the background is still `transparent`?

Comment: @Scar ..You should put the DRAWABLE inside the Linearlayout not inside the Edittext

Comment: Okay I've made some minor tweaks and I've met the desired output. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

Just use a Fram layout it works well use a frame layout and inside it edit text and an image view is created set the background of image view to transperent and gravity to the right or to the left

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="25dp">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border_round"
    android:drawableLeft="@color/place_autocomplete_search_text"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/places_ic_search"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrowxml">
</EditText>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:src="@drawable/searcharrow"
    android:layout_height="25dp" />
```

Answer (score -1):

use this...........

```
             <EditText
                android:id="@+id/user_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/editback"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/useremail"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:hint="@string/user_name"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#9291A1"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Comment: unfortunately, I already tried this. The padding of the image is still there